# MapsActivity Android not working in one project but project from scratch works

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one Android project, in which I want to use Google Maps in one activity. For that, I used the template available in Android Studio. I changed the API Key and the maps isn't shown. You also don't see any error in the logs, like if you use a wrong API Key. And the screen turns into a beige colour, with the Google logo in the corner.

However, if I start a project from scratch, and add the Maps Activity from the template (like I did in the other project), and with the same API Key, I can see the map.

So, I have no idea what's wrong. The project in which Google Map isn't working has authentication and some other dependencies. Is that maybe affecting it?

Comment: Can you please provide your code (for the project in which the map doesn't load), build.gradle and manifest? Also is your API key restricted? If so try unrestricting it for testing purposes.

Comment: thanks for you answer. But finally found the solution, I implemented the Sign in functionality, later on the maps, and it looks like it does not work like that. But after I sign in again the map loads properly.

Comment: I see, thanks for your update! Glad to hear your map's up and running now. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is due to the fact that the sign in functionality was doing something strange. Once I have to sign in again (with Google), then the map worked.